# How to set a 10 second limit to video recording and in real time remove the 10 seconds old film parts - Swift iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera, record

I can understand if the title is really confusing, but I'm going to do my best to explain more in detail! I have plans on an iOS Swift app that will record a video with a time limit of 10 seconds. But when the clip reaches 10 seconds, it should not stop recording. It should remove the end of the clip, so it never gets longer than 10 seconds. So it don't take up so much memory. And when someone presses the "stop-recording-button" it saves it to the camera roll.

I've searched the web for something like this, but I haven't fount anything helpful. Do you know a good tutorial or even a source code?

//Thanks in advance, Anton

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048425/cutting-video-on-iphone

Comment: That's Objective-C, and I don't have the skills to translate the code @MidhunMP

Comment: Can you check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660975/swift-crop-and-export-video/27661229#27661229

Answer (score 12):

Use the property:

[`videoMaximumDuration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/)

Comment: Is there any property for file size limit?

Comment: @Sudhakar there is maxRecordedFileSize in AVCaptureFileOutput

Answer (score 3):

You have a kinda confusing question. You don't want to stop recording but you just want to remove the end of the clip? Why not just stop the recording after 10 seconds?

You can use dispatch_time to stop, works for me:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {

    captureOutput.maxRecordedDuration = CMTimeMake(10, 1)

    /* After 10 seconds, let's stop the recording process */
    let delayInSeconds = 10.0
    let delayInNanoSeconds = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delayInNanoSeconds, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        captureOutput.stopRecording()
    })

    return
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If recording using `AVFoundation` should set maximum recorded duration when adding `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` to `AVCaptureSession`.

```
private let session = AVCaptureSession()
private let movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

movieOutput.maxRecordedDuration = CMTime(seconds: 10, preferredTimescale: 600)
if session.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
    session.addOutput(movieOutput)
}
```

After max recording duration `fileOutput(didFinishRecordingTo:from:error:)` will be called with your video saved to specified URL with duration some milliseconds below max. Note that error will not be nil.